# iOS image assets and App Store approval

Tags: ios, app-store, retina-display, asset-catalog, uiimageasset

I have my iOS app where I don't have a different image for different resolutions.

for example let's say we have backbutton. I have a image for 1x but not for 2x and 3x but when i run it on devices I don't get any problem with that.

[xcode image assets screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbX4u.png)

I have already sent the package to my client for App Store process ... now I am worried if apple will turn down my application because I don't have set of image supporting all the devices.

Kindly clarify this issue

**Update:**

Can you clarify me one thing ? lets say I have an image at just 1x of image in image asset catalog but I left 2x and 3x unfilled.

So when the app is running in retina screen ... will it go blank or it'll try to re-use the image of 1x for 2x devices or 3x devices

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of apps out there for Mac and websites that you can make a full catalog of images I use https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/asset-catalog-creator-free/id866571115?mt=12 myself. You can add all the required images then upload a new build and just change the build in iTunes-connect, however if you do choose to change the build then it will be taken out of the queue, but I have found apple normally only takes about 2 days to approve a build. (in my experience however sometimes they have been known to take 2 weeks apparently). My suggestion would be just to wait and see what they say, if they reject it its no big deal, just make the changes they suggest and resubmit it. However if you are worried change the build.

Hope this helps.

Comment: will apple reject my existing app ?

Comment: Its hard to say, I couldn't tell you personally, but I think just wait. Very few apps get approved on their first submission. Just make sure to improve upon the points apple recommends if it is rejected. Don't be to worried about it. It certainly does help apple if it is as best as you believe you can possibly make it when you submit it from revision. I recommend you read apples documentation on the matter. let me see if I can find the link

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/    https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/    https://developer.apple.com/library/content/navigation/

Comment: Thanks for the app link

Comment: One of the things Apple are known for is their design and attention to detail, so if the icon disappears all together, I would think they most likely would reject it. On the otherhand if it is blown up i suspect it should be fine. Like i said just wait it out and see what Apple say